# Bare bone case of react-transition-group for modal that doesn't work (codesandbox), why?

Tags: reactjs, react-transition-group

Just want to do a quick modal popout animation with `react-transition-group`

> current behavior:
>   https://codesandbox.io/s/525zj4vwrk
>
> expected result:
>   https://codesandbox.io/s/7m9721y03x

Similar code, but somehow the first one doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Just missing an [unmountOnExit](http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/transition#Transition-prop-unmountOnExit) property.

`<CSSTransition in={show} timeout={300} classNames="alert" unmountOnExit>`

**Working example** (if you don't like the button popping underneath the "modal" on fade out, then like the other example, use two sets of `state` with `onEnter` and `onExited` properties) :

[image: Edit Transition Example]

Comment: Thank you. 

1. Why does it need `unmountOnExit `? I imaging the card's opacity should be 0 when exited. 
2. And also if I apply opacity: 0 style to the card, it's acting weird with blinking. Why?

Comment: 3. And honestly do you think react-transition-group is still the go to option for react animations? Do you use something else like react-spring?

Comment: It needs `unmountOnExit` to remove it from the `DOM`. Otherwise, it's always present (hence the flashing animation you were getting). I personally don't use animations. While they may look great on screen, they can take up valuable resources and add unnecessary wait times. Most web applications (like target, reddit, and imgur) have very few (if any) animations. Performance is prioritized over "cool".